# Upload data from Field Maps after accidentally deleting layer features in AGOL

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-field-maps

I thought I was working in a separate copy of the layer so I deleted everything from the attribute table and discovered it was also deleted from the original layer. Big mistake. I still have the features in Field Maps on my phone. Can I upload the data back to AGOL?

Comment: There is sqlite database on your phone. Copy it to PC

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here using iTunes to save the files. https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-access-offline-edits-from-arcgis-field-maps-dire-000026799

Comment: We have a policy to delete link-only answers because they are external dependencies. You need to summarize the solution detailed in the link so it could be still found if the link failed.